# How to Import moment initial object to reduce import cost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

**This is my current state:**

This is the current import moment file size.

```
 import moment from "moment"; // 235.4k cost
```

I am using moment like this in my code :

```
  let d = moment(value)
```

**How to effectively extract the moment object for my use case and reduce the file cost.**

Comment: check whether this help https://github.com/kirillgroshkov/moment-mini-ts